# A positive number, it's integral part and decimal part form a geometric progression. Then the greatest integer less than or equal to the number is?

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, geometric-progressions

Let the number be $x$.
Integral part of the number $=[x]$
Decimal part of the number $=x-[x]$

Now as per the question $x,[x] $ and $x-[x]$ form a geometric progression. So :- 
$[x]^2=x(x-[x])$

Now I am not able to proceed from here. How can we solve this equation? Please help !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Well, $x$ can't be much greater than $\lfloor x\rfloor$  while the fractional part of $x$ is usually a lot smaller than $\lfloor x\rfloor$ so that tells you a lot about how big the ratio must be .  Start there.

Comment: The integer lower than $x$ is usually written as $\lfloor x\rfloor$, where you get the symbols with the latex commands `\lfloor` and `\rfloor`.

Comment: Let $x$ is integer part and $y$ is fractional part, then $y(x+y)=x^2$, $f(y)=y^2+xy-x^2=0$. At $x=0$ quadratic equation has one root $y=0$, then $x+y=0$ is not positive. At $x\neq 0$ quadratic equation for $y$ has two roots of different signs. $f(0)=-x^2<0$, then for positive root to be less than 1, $f(1)$ must be greater than 0. $1+x-x^2 > 0$, $x^2-x < 1$, $4x^2-4x < 4$, $(2x-1)^2 < 5$, $-\sqrt{5} < 2x-1 < \sqrt{5}$. $2x-1$ is integer, then $-3 < 2x-1 < 3$, $-2 < 2x < 4$, $-1 < x < 2$, and here $x\neq 0$. Then $x=1$. Then $f(y)=y^2+y-1=0$, $y=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$. $x+y=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $[x]=rx$ and $\{x\}=r^2x$, adding them we get

$$[x]+\{x\}=x(r^2+1)$$$$\implies x=x(r^2+r)$$$$\implies r^2+r=1$$$$\therefore r=\frac{\sqrt 5 -1}{2}$$

This means that $x$ has to be in the form of $\frac{2n}{\sqrt 5 -1}$ where $n$ is a positive integer, since $[x]=rx$. This means that $[x]=n$. But again, $\{x\}=r[x]$.
$$\therefore r[x] < 1$$
Substituting their values, we get

$$n < 1.618$$ or $n=1$ since $n$ is an integer.

So $$x=\frac{2n}{\sqrt 5 -1}=1.618$$

Comment: Can you please explain how did you get to the form of $x$?

Comment: @Ganit $xr$ is an integer and $r$ is $\frac{\sqrt 5 -1}{2}$. This means $x$ needs to have an even number in the numerator and ${\sqrt 5 -1}$ in the denominator so that  ${\sqrt 5 -1}$ which is not an integer gets cancelled out and we are left with an even number divided by $2$ which will leave us with an integer. The general form of an even number is $2n$ where $n$ is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Let the ratio be $\alpha$ then $\alpha x=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $\alpha \lfloor x\rfloor = x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ gives us $\alpha^2 x=x-\alpha x$. Using the quadratic equation, the solution for $\alpha$ is $x$ times the golden ratio, $\phi=1.61803...$, or its inverse $1/\phi=0.61803...$, and the integer requirement for $\alpha x$, and the requirement for $\alpha^2 x<1$ because of the decimal, gives us $x=\phi$, thus the sequence must be $\phi, 1, {1\over \phi}$. The greatest integer part of the question is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: You need $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ to be the next term in the geometric progression.